# Apache 403 when accessing via IP

Tags: macos, network, apache

I'm running a web server on Yosemite but have run into a bit of an issue. I can access web server via localhost, 127.0.0.1 and locally on other computer server.local.

But I can't access it via IP address i.e. 192.168.0.100 or by internet IP I get the following error message

Error code 403.
Message: Not Serving Client 82.15.XX.XXX.
Error code explanation: 403 = Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.

Comment: How did you install Apache?

Comment: Just worked out what it was I was also running plex connect on the same machine which uses port 80 so when I was trying to hit via ip I was hitting plex connect not web server.

Comment: @MarkBrown I have the same issue. Since Plex Connect is mainly using another port (`http://plexconnect.host:32400/`), is there a way to have a custom page in port 80 (`http://plexconnect.host:80/`)? (to have something like a help or a redirect page pointing to the 32400 port)

Answer (score 1):

I just want to echo what @Gik said. I was having the same problem but didn't notice the answer because it was a comment. PlexConnect was causing the issue. To resolve, Run the PlexConnect script in Applications/PlexConnect-master/support/OSX uninstall.bash